# GCC/Clang How can I Force no Undefined Symbols?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang

I am making a program in C using GCC/Clang to compile, and I have the following issue: I am trying to make sure that the compiler doesn't let me leave any symbols in my program undefined. I understand that translation units should be able to compile with undefined symbols, but I don't want it to link any static libraries unless it can find all of its internal symbols. For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World.\n");
}
```

I would expect that this program should compile, but it should not link (unless of course, I can find a way to state that `add` is a part of a shared library), which is not the case, it compiles with no warnings nor errors, even with `-Werror -Wall --pedantic-errors`. Is there any option in GCC/Clang that won't let a static library be compiled unless all of the internal symbols are defined? Otherwise, I think this is a disaster waiting to happen, especially in larger projects.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: "but it should not link". Why do you think that? `add` is never actually used.

Comment: I understand that, but I mean *ideally* i don't want it to link; I want to force it to not link. That is my question.

Comment: But but but...there are no undefined symbols. A prototype does not create any symbol references. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Or are you just giving an example that doesn't actually illustrate the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want it to make sure that all the prototypes are implemented, but only for static libraries, as this would not work in shared libraries.

Comment: Comically oversized hammer solution: compile with `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only -fno-diagnostics-color` and collect the output. A prototype generates a `FunctionDecl`. Extract the names of all of those. Generate a new function that takes pointers to all those functions (you can print them or something). If this links, you have no orphan prototypes.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother. The potential disaster is fairly self-limiting. If somebody uses an abandoned prototype, they should find out fairly quickly that the program stopped working. Don't you have testing in place?

Comment: @dratenik I do have testing in place, but I just think it would be a nice feature. If it's really that hard to do with the compiler, could anyone maybe recommend a static analyser that can look for that sort of thing?